# Custom AdapterView for Pie Chart

Tags: java, android, performance, android-adapterview

So I have created a custom AdapterView for a pie chart view that I'm using. I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong but the pie chart is pretty choppy when I try to rotate it.  I suspect too much drawing is going on as traceview shows a lot of calls to Canvas.nDrawDisplayList, which is not directly in my control.

I've placed a sample project on github to checkout (https://github.com/saulpower/ExpandablePieChart).  It is a cool little library if I can get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved everything to a surfaceview and got pretty good performance now.